# How do I fetch a JDBC connection in a hibernate 4.3 Integrator?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, orm, multi-tenant

When implementing an `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` for hibernate 4.3, one gets a `Configuration`, `SessionFactoryImplementor` and `SessionFactoryServiceRegistry` object.

One way to fetch the metadata is to obtain a connection provider:
`sessionFactory.getJdbcServices().getConnectionProvider()`

But `getConnectionProvider()` is deprecated and does not work for a multi tenant setup.

Javadocs say

> Access to connections via `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcConnectionAccess` should be preferred over access via `ConnectionProvider`, whenever possible.

But my problem is, that I don't find a way to obtain a `JdbcConnectionAccess`. It would be possible to use the given `SessionFactoryServiceRegistry` and replicate the code from `SessionFactoryImpl#buildLocalConnectionAccess()`, but that is not a nice solution.

What is the recommended way to fetch a connection in an `Integrator`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution until now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with deprecated method "sessionFactory.getJdbcServices().getConnectionProvider()". I used this function to get the dataSource for my FlywayIntegrator. I used them like in this example: http://blog.essential-bytes.de/flyway-hibernate-und-jpa-integrieren

Without the getConnectionProvider() i didn't found a solution to get the needed properties to connect with my database.

As a workaround i putted these properties in the standalone.xml file of my jboss configuration like this:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="com.mycomp.myapp.servername" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="com.mycomp.myapp.databasename" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="com.mycomp.myapp.databaseuser" value="yyy"/>
    <property name="com.mycomp.myapp.databasepassword" value="zzz"/>
</system-properties>
```

In my flyway integrator i can now read these properties by:

```
private DataSource getDataSourceFromSystemProperty() {
    String servername = System.getProperty("com.mycomp.myapp.servername");
    if (servername == null || servername.isEmpty()) {
        logger.warning("No system property found in standalone.xml file for com.mycomp.myapp.servername");
        servername = "localhost";
    }
    String databaseName = System.getProperty("com.mycomp.myapp.databasename");
    if (databaseName == null || databaseName.isEmpty()) {
        logger.warning("No system property found in standalone.xml file for com.mycomp.myapp.databasename");
        databaseName = "xxx";
    }
    String databaseUser = System.getProperty("com.mycomp.myapp.databaseuser");
    if (databaseUser == null || databaseUser.isEmpty()) {
        logger.warning("No system property found in standalone.xml file for com.mycomp.myapp.databaseuser");
        databaseUser = "yyy";
    }
    String databasePassword = System.getProperty("com.mycomp.myapp.databasepassword");
    if (databasePassword == null || databasePassword.isEmpty()) {
        logger.warning("No system property found in standalone.xml file for com.mycomp.myapp.databasepassword");
        databasePassword = "zzz";
    }

    final PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
    dataSource.setServerName(servername);
    dataSource.setPortNumber(5432);
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
    dataSource.setUser(databaseUser);
    dataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Maybe this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I need the `Connection` to obtain metadata about the connection (e. g. API level). Therefore configuring the details is no option.

Answer (score 1):

Getting connection in Integrator.integrate() method in Hibernate 5 could be done by:

```
final DataSource ds = (DataSource) sessionFactory.getProperties().get("hibernate.connection.datasource");
final Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: This was working fine and the most simple solution, without providing any extra parameters (like Gatschet's solutiuon). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following from your Integrator implementation:

```
SessionImplementor sessionImplementor = (SessionImplementor) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Connection conn = sessionImplementor.getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection();
```

The sessionFactory here is the SessionFactoryImplementor you receive from your implemented methods.

Comment: In the integrator there is no current session so a `HibernateException` with the message `No CurrentSessionContext configured!` is thrown.

Comment: Oups... Do you use the HibernateUtil pattern? Would it work if you use sessionFactory.openSession() instead, either from the session factory obtained in the method parameter, of from your HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory() ?

Comment: No, I don't us the HibernateUtil pattern. I use hibernate in a JPA environment and use a library to extend the supported basic types. The library integrates into hibernate implementing an `Integrator`. But at runtime it is not possible to fetch a `SessionImplementor` using `sessionFactory.openTemporarySession()`.